# Alpha blending is too smooth

Tags: textures, alpha-blending

I got the exercise to create a color map from a heightfield and given normals with alpha blending. 
Therefore I have to blend 4 textures (deep-flat, deep-steep, high-flat, high-steep) depending on the height and slope.

First I'm calculating the 3 alpha values (lowest layer is fully opaque, does not need to be blended -> gras texture)

```
//slope:= 1.0f - normal.z at current pixel

￼void calcAlphas(float height, float slope, float& alpha1, float& alpha2, float& alpha3) {
   alpha1 = (1-height) * slope; //low-steep ->  dirt texture
   alpha2 = height;             //high-flat ->  pebbles texture
   alpha3 = height * slope;     //high-steep -> rock texture
}
```

After that I'm getting the color at the current pixel of all four textures and calculating the final color:

```
3 = 3 ∗3 +(1−3)∗(2 ∗2 + 1−2 ∗(1∗1 + 1−1 ∗0))
```

The result looks pretty good but it's very smooth. To compare my result I got a pattern how it should be.

Orignal:

[image: Original]

My own color map:

[image: My own color map]

Comment: Your final alpha calculation has some weird characters on it that aren't rendering on my machine.  You should also mention what alpha blending mode you're setting things to.